# C# SQL Transaction (Process ID 72) was deadlocked

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

I have created a WinForm in Visual Studio which multiple users will access. 
Whenever a user access the data I want to lock the data so that the other users cannot view the same data at the same time due to some business logic.

Below is my c# code

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectString))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand("get_First_Unscan_Record_withUpdate",conn))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usrName", username_Form);
        conn.Open();
        record_number = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    }
}
```

And My SQL Procedure

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[get_First_QC_Record_withUpdate]
@usrName nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

Declare @srno int

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;

select top 1 @srno=srno from [KYC].[dbo].[KYC_Index] (XLOCK) where  [qc]='N' and [qc_int]='N' and transform_int='Y' and transform_status='Y' order by srno

update KYC_Index set [qc_int]='Y',[qc_int_by]=@usrName,[qc_int_time]=GETDATE(),@srno=KYC_Index.srno where srno = @srno

select @srno
```

Still my users are getting deadlock error

> {"Transaction (Process ID 72) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction."}

**What am I doing wrong? Or should I change? Please guide.**

Comment: This is not how you implement a queue. Have a single `update top (1)` with `rowlock, holdlock, readpast`, have it `output` the id, and have an index that covers all fields you are filtering on.

Comment: You don't deadlock with *one* thing - you deadlock with **two**. You already have an `XLOCK` (personally I'd have gone with `UPDLOCK`), so it can't be simply a read lock trying to become an update lock. So: do you have a transaction here? there isn't one in your code, but there could be a `TransactionScope` in play which could add other locks to your context/SPID.... is there? It kinda feels like you could do all of this in one SQL operation, though ... maybe via an `OUTPUT` clause to get the `srno`? The first thing I'd try, though, is using `UPDLOCK`. Then I'd try re-writing as single SQL op.

Comment: @GSerg Are you suggesting something like this?

update t1 set [qc_int]='Y',[qc_int_by]=@usrName,[qc_int_time]=GETDATE(),@srno=t1.srno from KYC_Index t1  with (UPDLOCK,HOLDLOCK) where t1.srno = (select top 1 t2.srno from KYC_Index t2 where t2.[qc]='N' and t2.[qc_int]='N' and t2.transform_int='Y' and t2.transform_status='Y' order by t2.srno)

Comment: No, that is still two queries disguised as one.

Comment: @GSerg We have requirement to update the data in SRNO order. Thatswhy two queries. Can you please direct me the right direction in the above scenario.

Comment: I think there's a second bit of SQL here that is causing the problem; some SQL that does something very similar (read then update), but **without** the lock hint. Do you by any chance have a similar bit of SQL that sets `qc_int` to `N`?

Comment: @MarcGravell No. But I have a data reader after this which gets the records from the srno after this code. 

record_number = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

Comment: This stored procedure is *guaranteed* to cause deadlocks, especially if the number of rows is small. Simply calling this twice from different connections will lock take locks on *ALL* rows that match the flags. Not just the first one.  The locks could easily escalate to table locks.

Comment: Besides, `I want to lock the data so that the other users cannot view the same data ` that has nothing to do with *queueing* or *locking* at all. That's a checkout. Use a `Checkouts` table where you record who checked out something and when and exclude any checked out records from queries. Don't try to implement *business functionality* like check-out/check-in with *database* concurrency mechanisms like locks

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos What do you mean by checkouts? Can you direct me to a link/url to some examples from which I can derive a solution.

Comment: @MarcGravell  I have made the srno field as a clustered index in SQL database and now my users are not getting deadlock. Is indexing the solution?

Answer (score -2):

You cannot hide the data by locking it. To hide from other users, there must be column like `hidden` in the same table or better in externally linked table like `hidden_rows`. `SERIALIZABLE` level is also not necessary. You need only `BEGIN TRAN` / `COMMIT TRAN` or you can do the same from C# side (begin_tran - try { do_work, commit_tran } catch { rollback }).

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86773566(v=vs.110).aspx

In `SELECT` statement use `(UPDLOCK)` hint - it will lock the row for writing until end of transaction and it will be readable for others.

Comment: From what I can see, the intent here is for `qc_int`  / `qc_int_by` / `qc_int_time` to **be** your `hidden` column - it is recording a: that it is "locked", b: who by, and c: when; re `UPDLOCK` - the code is using `XLOCK` which *should* cover that *and more*, no?

Comment: @MarcGravell "UPDLOCK does not block concurrent SELECT nor INSERT, but blocks any UPDATE or DELETE" - my recommendation was not to lock the row for reading (select). I suppose hiding is not necessary but the author thinks that it will protect data from concurrent edit. The problem is that usually the UI shows the record and it can be shown for 2+ users in the same time. Then such hiding will not help - both users can edit and save the changes. The locking/hiding occurs only in the moment of clicking "save" / "OK" button.

Comment: PS: With `hidden` column the software can hide a record when it is loaded in UI for editing and "show" after editing is finished.

Comment: @i486 the name isn't important; calling it `hidden` won't change how it works - `qc_int` works just the same

Comment: @i486 re the lock: you can't just talk about whether it blocks selects; you need to add the context *of the lock being specified*. So yes, while an UPDLOCK won't block a *regular* select, it **absolutely will** block another select **that specifies UPDLOCK**, because U/U=C in the Complete Lock Compatibility Matrix. Also, a `updlock` *can* block `insert`, *if* the select required a key range lock (because: serializable)

Comment: @MarcGravell We are talking about different things. I suggest a new organization and way of thinking. You comments current names of columns. Please explain why is necessary `XLOCK` when the isolation level is `SERIALIZABLE`?

Comment: @i486 oh, I agree *there* - see my comment on the question - I'd have used `UPDLOCK` too; but: you remarked that "UPDLOCK does not block concurrent SELECT ..." - which is simply untrue *if* the SELECT in question is specifying (as in this case) a higher lock type

Comment: I also am struggling to replicate. Happened six times (although 3 have the same timestamp)